# Difference between os.File, io.Reader and os.Stdin

Tags: file, go, operating-system

I was looking at [NewScanner](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewScanner) in the official go docs and it mentions the parameter to be passed to `bufio.NewScanner` should be of type `io.Reader`. However, the following works for me:

```
file, err := os.Open("filename")
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
```

The same can be seen for `os.Stdin` as well. Given this what is the difference between `os.File`, `os.Stdin` and `io.Reader` ? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: io.Reader is an interface. os.File and os.Stdin implement this interface having method Read() and can be used where io.Reader expected

Comment: @Projjol `os.File` is a *concrete* type, your `file` is a variable of that type, `os.Stdin` is also a variable of that same type. `io.Reader` is an *interface* type, the `os.File` type implements the `io.Reader` interface, therefore the values `file` and `os.Stdin` can be used as an argument to NewScanner.

Comment: thanks @Uvelichitel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `bufio.NewScanner` has `io.Reader` as an argument.

```
func NewScanner(r io.Reader) *Scanner
```

and `io.Reader` is the interface that wraps the basic Read method.

```
type Reader interface {
        Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

From the [os package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open) in Golang:

> Open opens the named file for reading. If successful, methods on the
>   returned file can be used for reading; the associated file descriptor
>   has mode O_RDONLY. If there is an error, it will be of type
>   *PathError.

```
func Open(name string) (file *File, err error)
```

The returned value `*os.File` implements `io.Reader`.

So whetever implements Reader interface can be passed as an argument to any method has [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) as an argument.